# Meteor takes time to know if there's a {{currentUser}} or not

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I've a few code that I want to run only when there's `noUser` and a few when there's a `currentUser`.
All these are inside the navigation template. Like so...

```
   {{#if currentUser}}  
     <li class="nav"><a href="{{pathFor 'create'}}">Post</a>  
     </li>  
     <li class="nav"><a>Ola, {{thisUser}}!</a>  
     </li>  
     <li class="nav"><a href="#" id="logout">Log Out</a>  
     </li>  
   {{/if}}  

   {{#if noUser}}  
      <li class="nav"><a href="{{pathFor 'signup'}}">Sign Up</a>  
      </li>  
      <li class="nav"><a href="{{pathFor 'login'}}">Login</a>  
      </li>  
   {{/if}}
```

So the problem is that when there's a `currentUser`(i.e, I'm logged in) and I refresh the page, the code inside the `{{#if noUser}}` block shows up first then the `{{#if currentUser}}` block, **while the `{{#if noUser}}` block was only meant to show up when there is no user.**
Here's the helper code for the template..

```
Template.navigation.helpers({

    thisUser: function () {
            return Meteor.user().username;

    },

    noUser: function () {
        var user = Meteor.user();

        if (!user) {
            return true;
        };
    }


});
```

Don't know what am I doing wrong here. :(
Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use if else conditions instead of noUser helper. And to prevent showing "noUser" block while logging in you have to use [{{ loggingIn }} helper](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_loggingin). Something like this:

```
{{#if loggingIn}}
  <p>Loggin in...</p>
{{else}}
  {{#if currentUser}}  
    <li class="nav"><a href="{{pathFor 'create'}}">Post</a>  
    </li>  
    <li class="nav"><a>Ola, {{thisUser}}!</a>  
    </li>  
    <li class="nav"><a href="#" id="logout">Log Out</a>  
    </li>  
  {{else}}  
    <li class="nav"><a href="{{pathFor 'signup'}}">Sign Up</a>  
    </li>  
    <li class="nav"><a href="{{pathFor 'login'}}">Login</a>  
    </li>  
  {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

Because Meteor does not know immediately whether user is logged in or not. Therefore you have to use loggingIn helper.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you refactor your code like this ?

```
{{#if currentUser}}  
  <li class="nav"><a href="{{pathFor 'create'}}">Post</a>  
  </li>  
  <li class="nav"><a>Ola, {{thisUser}}!</a>  
  </li>  
  <li class="nav"><a href="#" id="logout">Log Out</a>  
  </li>  
{{else}}  
  <li class="nav"><a href="{{pathFor 'signup'}}">Sign Up</a>  
  </li>  
  <li class="nav"><a href="{{pathFor 'login'}}">Login</a>  
  </li>  
{{/if}}
```

You might want to have a look to http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loggingin to show a loading indicator if needed.