# Flash of login screen while user is logginIn in Meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Forgive me if this is an absolutely dumb question but I have spent like a day trying to fix this but just couldn't. So, I am using accounts-templates which has been recently renames to useraccounts. Specifically I'm using the unstyled version. On my home route(using Iron Router), I have the following code:

```
Router.configure({
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    onBeforeAction: function(pause) {
      return AccountsTemplates.ensureSignedIn.call(this, pause);
    }
  });
});

Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
```

But when I load up the home page, there is this flash showing the login page and then the home template loads up. Ideally a progress bar should show up while the user is logging in and everything runs smooth.

I tried solving this with the iron-router-progress which I found out, doesn't work with Meteor 1.0. Then I tried integrating nprogress but that didn't work. So what's the solution?

Comment: Which version of iron:router are you using?

Comment: @will Its using version 1.0.0

Comment: A lot of changes have come in for version 1.0 of iron router. You should check out Chris Mather's recent talk on the changes and update your code. Not sure if this will fix it but your code will be up to date at least. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLd6fDi5UYE

Comment: So with the current code, it should be working?

Comment: I think it would of in 0.9.4 but not since the newer version came out. I could be wrong and the issue could be that it's loading the page before the users collection has been populate in which case a waitOn function should resolve it.

Comment: I think its now called multiply:iron-router progress instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the onBeforeAction to something along the lines of this, not guaranteeing this will work mind but it at least brings you up to date with the changes form 0.9.4 iron router to 1.0.0.

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    onBeforeAction: function() {
      if (! Meteor.userId()) {
        this.render('loading');
      } else {
        this.next();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I was able to fix my problem (which may have been slightly different to yours) with the {{ if loggingIn }} helper as the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575551/meteor-takes-time-to-know-if-theres-a-currentuser-or-not

Answer (score 0):

UserAccounts (formerly AccountsTemplates) has now (since versin 1.8.0) an `ensureSignedIn` plugin for Iron Router.
No more flashes!

See the updated documentation about [Content Protection](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#content-protection) to understand how to use it.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of UserAccounts